# Disable AWS X-Ray in java application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-xray

I am looking for option to **disable the AWS X-Ray in my java** application so it wont create/record any segment. Java application is built in spring boot and its deployed on EC2

Like global recorder to disable sampling and instrument all incoming requests.
Reason behind is our application will be deployed sometimes in to the clients AWS environment and they don't want that tracing should be enabled.

I could see there is **option available to disable Xray for python** (AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python-configuration.html) to do that but i couldn't find similar option for the java.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to disable tracing using the X-Ray SDK for Java. It's in our backlog to implement a similar type of environment variable for the Java SDK. While tedious, the best way I've seen customers implement a workaround is to make their instrumentation logic conditional on your own environment/system variable. E.g:

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard();

if (myTracingEnvVar == true) {
  client = client.withRequestHandlers(new TracingHandler(AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder()));
}

client.build();
```

Obviously this is far from convenient. If you'd like, we are always open to pull requests on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java).

Comment: this way it will only disable the globalrecorder but if xray client is not there(in non AWS env) then application will still still try to send the traces to the client and there will be error in the log. I was trying to disable the xray completely..

Comment: Unfortunately at this time the X-Ray SDK for Java cannot be disabled completely in the way you're describing. It is a feature in our backlog to implement. My best recommendation until we release such a feature is to use some condition like the one I described.

Comment: Thanks william . We haven't integrated AWS xray yet trying to figure it out which one would be better for our application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spring `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation in classes where you have the xray configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = false)
public class XRayConfig { ... }

@Aspect
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "AWS_XRAY_SDK_ENABLED",
    havingValue = "true",
    matchIfMissing = false)
public class XRayInspector extends AbstractXRayInterceptor { ... }
```

This allows you to create the beans conditionally based on the presence and value of the configuration property